# Subscription response data is ignored Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient, subscription

I'm making an HttpClient get request, and returning the response to my component.  I can't seem to do anything with the response.

Here is my component method calling the service:

```
  onSubmit() {
   this.userService.updateProfile(this.userForm.value)
     .subscribe(response => {
       console.log(response); //This does not log to the console
     });
  }
```

Here is my service:

```
  updateProfile(user: User) {
    return this.httpClient.put<User>('/updateUser', user)
      .map(response => {
        console.log(response); //This does not log to the console
        return response;
    });
  }
```

I am unable to get the response logged to the console in either my service or component.  I don't have any compilation errors or anything that indicates there is an issue.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It it possible on a put that you are not getting anything back to log? Many `put` operations don't return the data  like `get` and `post` do.

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I just tested with post request with no luck. I can't do a get request because i'm passing an object in the body.

Comment: Are you using `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post HTML code of form and component code? 
Also, your code should be something like:

```
 onSubmit() {
   this.userService.updateProfile(this.userForm.value)
     .subscribe(response => {
       this.response2 = response; //You need to assign it to something.
       console.log(response2); 
     });
  }
```

Just define response2 depending on type you need.
Same goes for the updateProfil function, you need to return it to something.

Comment: I did assign the response to an object, but removed it from my question in order to simplify it a bit.  I know the 'onSubmit()' is being fired because the user in my database does get updated, but I need to be able to reflect that from the UI with the updated user object.  I just can't see why i'm not getting any time of response logged in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my stupidity.  The issue was my server not sending a response.  I was certain it was, and mis-interpreted the code.  All working now.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. You should delete your questions since it was a non-issue.

Comment: can you make this a comment instead?